# Spoken Arabic dictionary/corpus?

Tags: corpora, arabic, dialects, dictionary, dialect-mapping

Is there an existing corpus or dictionary for different spoken Arabic dialects? I'd like to look up a word (in English or MSA or in a spoken dialect) and find where this word or phrase is spoken (and if the meaning is the same). A dialect map would also be really interesting.

In my case, I learned Tunisian Arabic, but I'd like to check if words and phrases I learned are shared with other dialects (like Moroccan or Levantine Arabic). Is there such a tool (or multiple corpora)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good starting place to look for corpora is the [CLARIN Virtual Language Observatory (VLO)](https://vlo.clarin.eu). [This query](https://vlo.clarin.eu/?q=spoken%20arabic&fqType=languageCode:or&fq=languageCode:code:ara) searches for "spoken arabic" and restricts the results to hits where the language is labelled as "Arabic". At the time of this writing it gives almost 700 hits.